# MySql:Group_Concat doesn't make group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

```
SELECT 
    D.Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT 
                C.Name
            FROM
                County AS C
                    INNER JOIN
                DealerCounty AS DC ON DC.CountyId = C.CountyId
                WHERE DC.DealerId = D.DealerId))
FROM
    Dealer AS D
```

As you can see my query I want to group county names by dealers. It returns, `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`
 How should I change my query?

Comment: All of the answers below work.  I would also recommend removing the sub-select and joining to the Count and Dealer County tables in your `FROM` statement.  I'm pretty sure that it would be more efficient, and definitely cleaner looking.

Comment: Actually, you *have* to remove to sub-query if it will return more than one row.  Add those tables to your FROM clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fine tuning along with the correction:

```
SELECT 
    D.Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)
FROM
    Dealer AS D
        JOIN County AS C ON DC.DealerId = D.DealerId
        JOIN DealerCounty AS DC ON DC.CountyId = C.CountyId
GROUP BY 
    D.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `group by` statement:

```
SELECT  D.Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT C.Name
                      FROM County AS C INNER JOIN
                           DealerCounty AS DC
                     ON DC.CountyId = C.CountyId))
FROM Dealer AS D
group by Name;
```

This version of the query, though, is much simpler:

```
select D.Name,
       group_concat(C.Name)
from Dealer D join
     County C
     on D.CountyId = C.CountryId
group by D.Name
```

Comment: Only the second solution will work.  In the first one, the Sub-Select will return more than one row and throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`Group by D.Name`**

```
SELECT 
    D.Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT 
                C.Name
            FROM
                County AS C
                    INNER JOIN
                DealerCounty AS DC ON DC.CountyId = C.CountyId
                WHERE DC.DealerId = D.DealerId))
FROM
Dealer AS D
group by D.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add aggregate function `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT D.Name,
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT C.Name
        FROM County AS C 
        INNER JOIN DealerCounty AS DC 
        ON DC.CountyId = C.CountyId
            ))
FROM Dealer AS D
GROUP BY D.Name
```